# OpenStreetMap data extraction

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

[image]
How can I extract all buildings, blocks, polygon features from OpenStreetMap?

I used OSMDownloader and QuickOSM QGIS plugin to download geospatial data for Saudi Arabia region. I was able to download some buildings, but I need all buildings from the selected region.

Comment: Please specify the spatial extent you are talking about. Also specify what "not complete" does mean in this context.

Comment: have you tried by: http://download.geofabrik.de/

Comment: Yes, i tried. it provide the same results

Comment: Than i think the info you are searching do not exist in OSM.

Comment: No buildings have been added to OpenStreetMap where you're looking, personally I think the best thing you could do it edit them into OSM your self and then add them to your project, perfect opportunity to contribute to OSM.

Comment: It's not possible to able to download buildings data until a volunteer adds them to OpenStreetMap.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed I think your comment would be a good answer

Answer (score 3):

No buildings have been added to OpenStreetMap where you're looking, personally I think the best thing you could do it edit them into OSM yourself and then add them to your project, perfect opportunity to contribute to OSM.